# Installing a fragment requires a refresh on the host, how can this be avoided?

Tags: osgi, osgi-fragment

I have two bundles: bundle A and bundle B which is configured as a fragment of bundle A using:
Fragment-Host:

Whenever I install bundle B it fails to start (INSTALLED) and therefore to attach itseld to bundle A.

At this point when I check bundle A's status I see that it still doesn't recognize bundle B as its fragment.

If I do refresh bundle A it solves the problem - bundle B switches to RESOLVED and is able to attach itself to bundle A, bundle A recognizes bundle B as its fragment and everything is working as expected.

My question is how this refresh can be avoided, i.e. as soon as bundle B is installed it should attach itself to its host which is already ACTIVE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do that without a refresh, and it's in the OSGI specs too - to properly attach a fragment bundle, a transition from INSTALLED to RESOLVED of the host bundle is necessary. See section 3.14 of the 4.3 OSGi Core Specification.

Comment: I thought so :( the thing is that even a container restart doesn't seem to resolve it only a refresh on the specific bundle host. Is that should be the case?

Comment: AFAIK yes, because the wiring between resolved packages/bundles is persisted. You will need to do this by hand, but you can do it programatically.

Comment: Not example code, but for OSGi 4.3 and later frameworks look at the `FrameworkWiring` and `BundleWiring` interfaces, and section 7.6 of the 4.3 OSGi Specification. For pre-4.3 frameworks look into the `PackageAdmin` service.

Comment: Thanks. Getting the host bundle through PackageAdmin and updating it seem to have solved it